# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Cannot parse "DATE" constant "DATEADD(DAY,-2,CURDATE())

Tags: h2, upgrade, liquibase

after upgrading to liquibase 3.9.0 and h2 1.4.200, I'm receiving this error message when trying to load data from a csv file. Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Cannot parse "DATE" constant "DATEADD(DAY,-2,CURDATE())"; Last versions it worked were liquibase 3.5.5 and h2 1.4.197.

Bellow is an example of how the csv is structured :

id;sender;client_code;status;title;streamfile_name;delivery_channel;delivery_time;delivery_address;viewed_time;visible_until;**document_date**;
Client;Test;USER_INTERACTION;test_document1;ESTDOCUMENT_1;null;null;null;null;null;**DATEADD(DAY,-2,CURDATE());**

POM looks like this:

```
    <liquibase.version>3.9.0</liquibase.version>
    <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.8</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
    <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
```

liquibase script:If I am not specifying the type of the field I receive the error mentioned above, if I specify it like this

> column name="document_date" type="date

Then I am receiving an error that the field cannot be null, as null values are not allowed there and because it cannot be parsed liquibase puts null.

Answer (score 0):

H2 doesn't have `currdate()`. You should use [current_date](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_date) instead.